# PyPy slower than CPython with file translator

Tags: python, pypy

I have a translator in Python (based on, as a result, similar to heat-translator [1]). It's running a bit slow. So I turned to PyPy. After switching to it, I found out that it's actually a bit slower.

So the project takes in a YAML file, parse it, transform the in memory tree, and spits out file in a different format - a bit like a compiler.

Is PyPy *not* suitable for this kind of use case? I thought it was designed for CPU bound tasks.

1. https://github.com/openstack/heat-translator

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing what YAML library you are using (PyYAML, `ruamel.yaml`) and your actual code, this cannot be explained definitively. However e.g. if you use the standard loading routine:

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

yaml = YAML(typ='safe')
with open('somefile.yaml') as fp:
    yaml.load(fp)
```

to load a YAML 1.2 (or 1.1) document from a file. You will actually use a reader/scanner written in C if you run this using CPython, and will be running the  pure Python version when you run it using PyPy.

Depending on the file the C based reader/scanner gives one to two orders of magnitude speed improvement loading a document, over the pure Python implementation, so I am not surprised that this cannot be equaled by PyPy compiling the Python.

In the past I briefly looked at using the C based reader/scanner when using PyPy as well, but that did not seem trivial, and since that C coded reader/scanner is outdated and needs upgrading, that plan was put on ice.

When using PyYAML (for outdated YAML 1.1 documents), a similar principle holds, although it will not automatically use a C based reader/scanner stage unless explicitly directed to do so.

Answer (score 0):

If you could create a benchmark that reflects your workload, you could submit it as an issue to PyPy https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/issues and as a PR to the python benchmark suite https://github.com/python/performance